# How can I display the images in the div within the id="leftSide"?

Tags: javascript

am currently in the middle of a Coursera assignment but cant get the leftSide div to display the images.

Could someone kindly advise what is wrong with my code? Thank you!

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Matching Game - Smiling :)</title>
<style>
    div, img {position: absolute;}
    div {width: 500px; height: 500px;}
    #rightSide {left: 500px; border-left: 1px solid black}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var numberOfFace = 5;
    var theLeftSide = document.getElementById('leftSide');
    var top_random = (Math.random() * 400);
    var left_random = (Math.random() * 400);
    var count = 0

    function generateFaces() {
        var smiling_face = document.createElement("img");
        document.getElementsByTagName("img").src="http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png" 
        img.src = "http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png";
        smiling_face.style.top = Math.floor(top_random);
        smiling_face.style.left = Math.floor(left_random);

        while (count < numberOfFace) {
            theLeftSide.appendChild(smiling_face);
            count = count ++;
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="generateFaces()">
    <h1>Matching Game</h1>
    <p>Click on the extra smiling face on the right!</p>
    <div id="leftSide"></div>
    <div id="rightSide"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is that `img` variable that does not seem defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code has multiple problems... and because it is not working properly, it is hard to guess which kind of outcome you want to accomplish.

But I found at least following problems:

1. `img` variable is never defined - and needs to be `smiling_face` instead.. this is probably a typo.
2. Typing of `document.getElementsByTagName("img").src="http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png"` is not required, because `smiling_face` will be placed to DOM at the end of the function loop.
3. `top_random` and `left_random` is defined outside `generateFaces()` so they always has the same value.. because it seems that you want to output 5 smile faces, you need to defined them inside the `generateFaces()` function.
4. Giving absolute position as `smiling_face.style.top = Math.floor(top_random);` is wrong.. you should also specify the pixel value.. so it becomes: `Math.floor(top_random) + "px";` Same applies to style.left ...
5. Increasing value of `count` can be done as `count++;`

After those changes, you will have a working example of creating 5 smiley images to randomised positions of a div.

Here is a **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/17j8puo3/2/)** example.

Relevant code also below:

**HTML:**

```
<h1>Matching Game</h1>
<p>Click on the extra smiling face on the right!</p>
<div id="leftSide"></div>
<div id="rightSide"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div, img {position: absolute;}
div {width: 500px; height: 500px;}
#rightSide {left: 500px; border-left: 1px solid black}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var numberOfFace = 5;
var count = 0;

function generateFaces() {
    var theLeftSide = document.getElementById('leftSide');

    while (count < numberOfFace) {
        var top_random = (Math.random() * 400);
        var left_random = (Math.random() * 400);
        var smiling_face = document.createElement("img");

        smiling_face.src = "http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png" 
        smiling_face.style.top = Math.floor(top_random) + "px";
        smiling_face.style.left = Math.floor(left_random) + "px";
        theLeftSide.appendChild(smiling_face);

        count++;
    }
}

generateFaces();
```

Note:

Even though I use `generateFaces();` call here as an example of triggering the method. You can use `<body onload="generateFaces()">` as you already have in place and keep the javascript at the head section of the page.. However, it is often preferred to place javascript before the closing body tag. -- Because, placing it to the head slows down initial page rendering as HTML parser needs to wait for external scripts to download before rendering rest of the document. However, using *async* keyword allows still place scripts to head as it removes the blocking behaviour. You can read more about this from here: [BlockingJS](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS)

Cheers.

Comment: Hi Mauno, thanks for your detailed explanation. I fixed the code and it works now. Just curious but why is it often preferred to place javascript before closing body tag?

Comment: @ShaneLow I tried explaining that in my answer. HTML is parsed top-down. So that means your JavaScript will be processed FIRST and then the rest of the HTML. Which means if you reference HTML that hasn't been parsed yet, you will get errors in your JavaScript. jQuery made this easy to put at the top by giving us a "wait for DOM" command, so the page loads first, then the JavaScript executes. I suggest you study your Coursera material more closely on how the underlying parsers/processes work as it will help you understand how all these pieces fit together

Comment: @ShaneLow It should be placed to bottom, because placing it to the head slows down initial page rendering. I updated my answer, read the final note at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

img is not defined, so comment out or delete the line that says:

```
  img.src = "http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png";
```

The other thing that is wrong is that your JavaScript runs first (doesn't wait for the page to render) which causes an "Object not found" Reference error when you're trying to reference the DIV, because the DOM hasn't loaded entirely yet.

Moving the JavaScript to the bottom of the page solves this issue.

Then another issue you're having is

```
count = count++;
```

This should just be:

```
count++;
```

Once you've solved all that, you will notice that the image still doesn't load:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("img").src="http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png";
```

Should be:

```
smiling_face.src="http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png";
```

The reason why document.getElementsByTagName("img") doesn't work is because you haven't used ".appendChild" yet to add "smiling_face" to the DOM. Because there are no "img" elements defined in the DOM yet, that will never fire/work. So you have to use the "smiling_face" element you already created (which I think img.src was from)

Comment: The last two lines of your answer are equivalent.

Comment: @callback no it's not. document.getElementsByTagName doesn't do anything because he hasn't used appendChild yet, so the DOM has no idea what he is saying. He is also adding "smiling_face" as an image element already, so defining that object's source is better than the non-existent one he is running. Copy and paste his code and run it in your browser and see. Both you and Shane don't know much about how JavaScript renders or what these commands mean

Answer (score -1):

Remove the following line :

`img.src = "http://home.cse.ust.hk/~rossiter/mooc/matching_game/smile.png";`